# Calling a php function when onchange fires from input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, onchange

Hello, I have an input field named `result`. I want to call a function when something changes in this input. I tried this :

```
<input onchange="maFonction" id="result" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="0" size = "10" />
```

And tried to call this function

```
<?php
function maFonction()
{

$a = 40 ;
if ($result > $a) {

     echo "trop dheure";
     } elseif ($result == $a) {
     ?>
                    <input onclick="s(this.form);" type="button" value="sauvegarder" /> 
        <?php
        } else {
    echo "moins de 40 heures a été effecuté";
}


}
?>
```

What mistake did I do or what am I missing?

Comment: Try something like `onchange="maFonction()"` using `()` for a function.

Comment: You can not call a PHP function directly using DOM events. Where is the AJAX call? How does it look like?

Comment: nothing change no message appear. and no error on console

Comment: I don'T have ajax for the moment I know ajax can make it but I don't know how to used it.

Comment: php already ends work... there is no any php function...

Comment: Just Google "how to call a javascript function with php" you'll find a whole bunch of results Bacon Man ;-) That did it, now I've got the Munchies!

Comment: Use javascript. NOT php for those functions in real-time

Comment: you can generate 40 inputs without php

Comment: i can do php in a javascript function?

Comment: To a certain extent, yes you can and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm not the only one who thinks the combination of an `onchange` event and a `readonly` field is odd, am I?

Comment: also you can do javascript in a javascript function... But jQuery required for this

Comment: @ Patrick Q this is a total showing. and if the number if superior of 40 then msg if equal another button appear if inferior msg apear did you read the code?

Comment: I'm confused as to how your onchange will happen using `readonly="readonly"` --- You need to show full code, this is too vague.

Comment: this is simple to understand yes this is readonly cause this is a total automatic calculate. NO one can change it this is like a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to use PHP, call a php file instead a function.

**Your form**

```
<form method="post" action="myfunc.php">
    <input type="text" name="myname">
    <input type="submit" value="click" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Your php file: myfunc.php**

```
<?php
function display()
{
    echo "hello ".$_POST["myname"];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   display();
} 
?>
```

Comment: this is not a button this is a input i cannot click . i really need if the number in the input change a message appear.

Comment: it's the idea to know how to call a function() with a form. From here on you know what and how to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onchange="maFonction()" id="result" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="0" size = "10" />
```

javascript

```
maFonction = function(){
$.post("yourFile.php");
}
```

and your php

```
<?php

$a = 40 ;
if ($result > $a) {

     echo "trop dheure";
     } elseif ($result == $a) {
     ?>
                    <input onclick="s(this.form);" type="button" value="sauvegarder" /> 
        <?php
        } else {
    echo "moins de 40 heures a été effecuté";
}


}

?>
```

Comment: why do you make this request? where you use its result?

Comment: I just call his php function from html using javascript

Comment: the message won't change when the input number change

Comment: How can the input number change when it can't be changed in the first place? `readonly="readonly"` @TheBaconManWithouBacon

Comment: I have 8 input. 7 to calcul for each day in one week and the last one is the result. If sunday i writes 8 hours , monday 5 hours .. and all of the 7 input is additionated and transfer into the result input. So i already use ajax for calculate the result when i change one of the day number is recalculate automaticly the result exemple : sunday 5, monday 5, tuesday 5, thurday 5, wenesday 5, friday 5, saturday 5  = 25  in the result. if I change monday for 4 in my result they recalculate and show 24. so I want when the number change a msg appear if under 40 superior of 40

Comment: @Fred -ii- the readonly used for people can change directly the total.